# Python- How to check if a word has lower and uppercases

Tags: python

I working on a school project.
I am confused on how to make the ( if ) statement detect a character with upper and lower cases.
I have tried to use 'and' in an if statement but it would be too long.
My current input is:

```
a=input('Line: ')
if 'robot' in a:
 print('There is a small robot in the line.')
elif ('robot'.upper()) in a:
 print('There is a big robot in the line.')
elif b in a:
 print('There is a medium robot in the line.')
else:
 print('No robots here.')
```

Don't mind the (b) I was just figuring out something I don't know how to explain.
An Output example I am looking for goes like:

```
There is a "robot" in the line
then it would print
'There is a robot in the line'
```

The program will check for both upper and lowercase characters.
If an input had all caps, it would print out
There is a big robot in the line
If an input had just lowercase letters then it would just print
there is a small robot in the line.
If an input with both lower and upper cases it would print:
There is a medium robot in the line.

Comment: Can you give an example of a medium case? You mean like RoBot?

Comment: Also, is you code supposed to work for "robotic", for example, or **only** the word `robot`

Answer (score 2):

You can lowercase the input first before checking if the lowercase `robot` is in the input string:

Change:

```
elif b in a:
```

to:

```
elif 'robot' in a.lower():
```

Comment: But then that's not separating `ROBOT` from `robot`, which would both be caught in the earlier cases

Comment: Please read the OP's code. His first two `if` expressions already test for lowercase and uppercase conditions, and I'm only helping him fix the third condition, which tests for mixed case. With `elif`, the third expression won't be evaluated unless the first two fails.

Comment: Got it. It wasn't clear to me you were only mentioning the third condition

Answer (score 0):

How about using `re` with `IGNORECASE` to check the (b) situation. It means match the words like 'robot','Robot','rObot'...

```
import re

def check_robot(s):
    if re.search(r"robot", s):
        print("There is a small robot in the line.")
    elif re.search(r"ROBOT", s):
        print("There is a big robot in the line.")
    elif re.search(r"robot",s,re.IGNORECASE):
        print("There is a medium robot in the line.")
    else:
        print("'No robots here.'")
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use not islower() and not isupper() to get the mixed string check. Here is the code which works!

```
    a=input('Line: ')
    if 'robot' in a:
        print('There is a small robot in the line.')
    elif ('robot'.upper()) in a:
        print('There is a big robot in the line.')
    elif not a.islower() and not a.isupper():
        print('There is a medium robot in the line.')
    else:
        print('No robots here.')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
words=["robot","ROBOT","ROBot","APPLE","Nuts"]
res=["UPPER" if w.isupper() else ("LOWER" if w.islower() else "MIXEDCASE") for w in words]  
print(res)
```

Output:

```
['LOWER', 'UPPER', 'MIXEDCASE', 'UPPER', 'MIXEDCASE']
```